# Pytorch: call other Module in for-loop over RNN timesteps

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I work with text data from human-machine dialog, where each dialog contains a number of turns (which in turn are a sequence of words), and I want to predict a label for each turn.

My idea is to use a recurrent neural network to loop over fixed-size turn representations that I compute with a simple Multilayer Perceptron based on some features (so no looping over the words in the turn here).

In the code sample below, this is how I do this.

My question: If I compute turn representations timestep by timestep within the `for` loop and then combine them via `torch.stack()`, will the loss finally backpropagate through all the MLP timesteps, i.e. all the forward computations? Or will only the last step in the `for` loop be considered for loss computation? Is there another way to do this?

PS: Because I want to compute different sets of features for different items in my training data, I need the turn MLP to transform turns to a fixed size, otherwise this would of course not be necessary.

```py
class TurnMLP(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    self.linear = nn.Linear(4, 20)
    super(TurnMLP, self).__init__()

  def forward(self, x_turn):
    return torch.sigmoid(self.linear(x_turn))

class DialogRNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    self.turn_mlp = TurnMLP()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(20, 15)
    self.dense = nn.Linear(15, 3)
    super(DialogRNN, self).__init__()

  def forward(self, x_dialog):  # x_dialog is a list of turns, a turn is a feature vector
    turns_hidden = []

    # Here comes the interesting part: is it okay to call the turn_mlp at each timestep and expect it to store all gradients? I guess not, right?
    for x_turn in x_dialog:
      turn_hidden.append(self.turn_mlp.forward(x_turn)
    turns_hidden = torch.stack(turns_hidden)
    turns_outputs, _ = self.lstm(turns_hidden)
    return torch.sigmoid(self.dense(turns_outputs))

# TRAINING
dialog_rnn = DialogRNN()

# a dialog with 3 turns, converted to feature vectors
sample_dialog = [torch.tensor([0,1,0,1]), torch.tensor([1,0,1,1]), torch.tensor([1,0,0,0])]  
sample_labels = torch.tensor([2,0,1])

prediction = dialog_rnn.forward(sample_dialog)
loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(prediction, sample_labels)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(dialog_rnn.parameters())

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using list of tensors for for x_dialog? If dimensions of all the tensors inside the list match, then we can use a 2D tensor instead of list of  1D tensors  and call the `TurnMLP.forward` on the whole tensor in one go, instead of using a for loop.

Comment: Yeah that's the point, the dimensions don't necessarily match. I can pad the sequences of course, but I was wondering if I could circumvent this with my solution.